# Reverting UI changes in Angular 2 when canceling two-way data binding

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

**UPDATE:**
adding code for clarification.

client.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ClientService } from "../services/client.service";
import { Client } from "../types/client";


@Component({
selector: "rpcs-client",
templateUrl: "/app/client/client.component.html",
providers: [ClientService]
})
export class ClientComponent {
private clients: Client[];
private newClient = new Client();
private client: Client;
private _cl: ClientService;


constructor(clientService: ClientService) {
    this._cl = clientService;

    this._cl.getAll()
        .subscribe(
        response => this.clients = response,
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Fetch clients complete.", this.clients)
        );
}


saveClient(client: Client) {
    this._cl.saveClient(client)
        .subscribe(
            response => this.client = response,
            err => console.log("Error: ", err),
            () => console.log("Save client complete.", this.clients)
        );

}

addClient(client: Client) {
    this._cl.addClient(this.newClient)
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.client = response;
            this.clients.push(this.client);
        },
        err => console.log("Error: ", err),
        () => console.log("Add client complete.", this.clients)
        );

}

deleteClient(clientId: number, client: Client) {
    this._cl.deleteClient(clientId, client)
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                this.client = response;
                // this.clients.splice(this.clients.indexOf(this.client), 1);
            },
            err => console.log("Error: ", err),
            () => console.log("Delete client complete.", this.clients)
        );
}


}
```

client.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { SpringfieldService } from "./springfield.service";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Client } from "../types/client";

@Injectable()
export class ClientService extends SpringfieldService {
private url = this.baseUrl + "Clients";

constructor(private http: Http) {
    super();

}

getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getClient(clientId: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.url, clientId)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

saveClient(client: Client) {
    return this.http.put(this.url, client)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

addClient(client: Client) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, client)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

deleteClient(clientId: number, client: Client) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${clientId}`)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

}
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I have a modal that allows you to edit the data in a database from the Web API app using Angular 2. Everything is working properly except for when we want to cancel the changes.

Whenever we hit cancel, the changes don't reflect in the database since nothing was saved, but it still shows in the user interface as you can see in the before and after images below. If I hit cancel with the "sss" added to New York State, the sss remain on the site until I refresh the page manually.

**BEFORE:**

[image: The Edit Client Modal loads current data]

**AFTER:**
[image: The Edit Client Modal displays edited data]

What I'm looking for is a way to make sure everything reverts back to its original state when clicking cancel. I've also included some snippets of the code being utilized. That being said, I'm not sure which code matters most regarding this issue.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditClientModal{{client.ClientId}}">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel2">
                                                Edit Client
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form #form="ngForm">
                <div>
                    <span>Client Name:</span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="clientName" id="clientName" [(ngModel)]="client.ClientName" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <span>Client Number:</span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="clientNumber" id="clientNumber" [(ngModel)]="client.ClientNumber" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="saveClient(client)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"/> Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any snippet presenting how your modal is actually shown, how the object is passed to it. But I think that problem is that you pass reference to the same object as presented in the table while you should operate on the copy of your data.

So while opening your modal you should copy the selected object and perform operations on this copy. Changes will not be reactively reflected in the table, so after saving you will have to update records displayed in the table. In this case you don't have to worry about reverting changes after cancel.

From UX point of view, with modal, it is also a better idea to update the records after save, than to update them during typing.

Comment: The copying idea sounds great, but how would I go about calling in a copy of the object rather than the object itself? I added some more code to the original post for clarification

Comment: Could you please also append the part responsible for showing the modal. The part in which the action of clicking edit button is presented?